# FPML and Powershell using XPath

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

Hi can someone help me with a script to parse FPML using powershell ?

It's a standard fpml file.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand FPML is just a specific type of XML?

```
[xml]$FPMLDoc = Get-Content "C:\FPML\Doc1.xml"
```

this will give you an XML object which you can navigate through, for example:

```
$FPMLDoc.Document.Items[0].Name
```

or whatever format your document may be in.

Comment: can you show me exactly what you typed? what is the output of just `$FPMLDoc` after you run the first command.

Comment: @NewbieCoder if you have a sample FPML file put it in the op, the format is important. (don't put any personal/financial info in the post though)

Comment: Actually I don't have a sample file :/ what I'm struggling with is using xpath to parse nodes and child nodes

Comment: Also not able to display the node text

Comment: @NewbieCoder with no idea what you're working with or trying to achieve, or what errors (if any) you're getting there's no real way to help you out.